# How to know which are the highest PageRanked pages in my site?

Tags: seo, pagerank

I have a large site where I would like to know which are the internal pages with higher PageRank for optimization purpouses. How can I generate a pagerank list of all my website pages?

Comment: If you have a list of your pages you could use http://ruediger.info, because you can: (1) Check several sites at once, (2) Get a link to the results which you could visit every month or even put on your website (3) and there are no annoying captchas. There is also one (in german): http://pagerank.comlex.de where it is directly possible to eMail the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I basically agree with Osvaldo [*], anyway if you want to see PR value for each page, you can use Firefox and install [SEOQuake plugin](http://www.seoquake.com/). It reports for each page the Google PR.

Once there was the Google Toolbar that was showing the PR of each page, but I think they removed that feature lately.

---

[*] I never understood why Google removed the PR in its toolbar, it was the only reason why I was using their toolbar. Even if it was just a number, I liked to see the PR of each page of my sites. It was like reading the vote given by Google to my site.

Comment: the problem is I have a "large site" :) Impossible to do it one by one

Comment: If you use Chrome, this plugin has the PR marker: http://any-tech.ws/page-rank/ (I use it and it works)

Comment: @Ivan: looking at the SEOQuake plugin it seems it calls a Google webservice to show you the PR of the page, so you might use such webservice too by creating a small PHP script that call such service for each page fo your webiste. http://toolbarqueries.google.com/tbr?client=navclient-auto&hl=en&ch=63273529084&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&features=Rank&q=info:http%3A%2F%2Fyour_page_url_here

Answer (score 1):

PageRank is not that important (for optimization purposes) anymore.

You can get tons of much more valuable info if you optimize your site for Google with Google Webmaster tools. You'll be able to see what pages score best for specific keywords, get CTR and number of clicks for each keyword. You can also see how many times each page was shown in search results and by which keywords.

With Webmaster tools, you'll be able to monitor which pages and keywords are gaining or losing visibility and clicks.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but there are some ad-managers that still want their banners appear in high PR pages. This is why I need to know it, because higher PR suppose sometimes better paid ads

Answer (score 0):

Aready exists, it's known as Google Analytics. Get it set up on your website and you can start tracking average page position by actual search keywords. Lots more statistics available and actually more useful than a generic logrithmic number that doesn't really mean anything.

[image]

Comment: But, is there a PR ranker? I haven't found it, and that's what I need :)

Comment: Page rankers used to be available till Google changed the API a couple times and people started looking at other stats to improve SEO and site performance. There are a couple websites out there that offer a free PR report on your website, not sure how deep or how many pages they will go.